# paho-mqtt : callback for when a PUBLISH message is not been received from the server

Tags: python, mysql, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

**mqtt_collector.py**

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json
import mysql.connector
from datetime import datetime

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="PASSWORD",
    database="mydatabase"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

# The callback for when the client receives a CONNACK response from the server.
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc == 0:
        print("Connected to MQTT broker")
        client.subscribe("CO_LVL")
    else:
        print("Connection failed with result code " + str(rc))

# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic + " " + str(msg.payload))
    data = json.loads(msg.payload)
    sensor = data["sensor"]
    co_level = data["CO level"]
    now = datetime.now()
    timestamp = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    if sensor == 2:
        if co_level > 100 and co_level <= 300:
            client.publish("client2/consistency", payload="moderate")
        elif co_level > 300:
            client.publish("client2/consistency", payload="high")
    elif sensor == 3:
        if co_level > 100 and co_level <= 300:
            client.publish("client3/consistency", payload="moderate")
        elif co_level > 300:
            client.publish("client3/consistency", payload="high")
    elif sensor == 4:
        if co_level > 100 and co_level <= 300:
            client.publish("client4/consistency", payload="moderate")
        elif co_level > 300:
            client.publish("client4/consistency", payload="high")
    try:
        mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO CO_MONITORING (`sensor`, `co_level`, `timestamp`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (sensor, co_level, timestamp))
        mydb.commit()
        print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        print("MySQL Error:", err)

client2 = mqtt.Client(client_id="fd00::202:2:2:2")  # linked to unit A
client2.on_connect = on_connect
client2.on_message = on_message
client2.connect("127.0.0.1", 1883, 60)

client3 = mqtt.Client(client_id="fd00::203:3:3:3")  # linked to unit B
client3.on_connect = on_connect
client3.on_message = on_message
client3.connect("127.0.0.1", 1883, 60)

client4 = mqtt.Client(client_id="fd00::204:4:4:4")  # linked to unit C
client4.on_connect = on_connect
client4.on_message = on_message
client4.connect("127.0.0.1", 1883, 60)

client2.loop_forever()
client3.loop_forever()
client4.loop_forever()
```

client_node.c

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2020, Carlo Vallati, University of Pisa
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 * 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 * 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *    documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 * 3. Neither the name of the copyright holder nor the names of its
 *    contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
 *    from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
 * ``AS IS'' AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS
 * FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT,
 * INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES
 * (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR
 * SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION)
 * HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT,
 * STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE)
 * ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED
 * OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "contiki.h"
#include "net/routing/routing.h"
#include "mqtt.h"
#include "net/ipv6/uip.h"
#include "net/ipv6/uip-icmp6.h"
#include "net/ipv6/sicslowpan.h"
#include "sys/etimer.h"
#include "sys/ctimer.h"
#include "lib/sensors.h"
#include "dev/button-hal.h"
#include "dev/button-sensor.h"
#include "dev/leds.h"
#include "os/sys/log.h"
#include "mqtt-client.h"
#include "node-id.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#define LOG_MODULE "mqtt-client"
#ifdef MQTT_CLIENT_CONF_LOG_LEVEL
#define LOG_LEVEL MQTT_CLIENT_CONF_LOG_LEVEL
#else
#define LOG_LEVEL LOG_LEVEL_DBG
#endif

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/* MQTT broker address. */

#define MQTT_CLIENT_BROKER_IP_ADDR "fd00::1"
static const char *broker_ip = MQTT_CLIENT_BROKER_IP_ADDR;
// Defaukt config values
#define DEFAULT_BROKER_PORT         1883
#define DEFAULT_PUBLISH_INTERVAL    (30 * CLOCK_SECOND)

// We assume that the broker does not require authentication
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/* Various states */
static uint8_t state;
#define STATE_INIT            0
#define STATE_NET_OK          1
#define STATE_CONNECTING      2
#define STATE_CONNECTED       3
#define STATE_SUBSCRIBED      4
#define STATE_DISCONNECTED    5
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
PROCESS_NAME(mqtt_client_process);
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&mqtt_client_process);
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Maximum TCP segment size for outgoing segments of our socket */
#define MAX_TCP_SEGMENT_SIZE    32
#define CONFIG_IP_ADDR_STR_LEN   64
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*
 * Buffers for Client ID and Topics.
 * Make sure they are large enough to hold the entire respective string
 */

#define BUFFER_SIZE 64

static char client_id[BUFFER_SIZE];
static char pub_topic[BUFFER_SIZE];
static char sub_topic[BUFFER_SIZE];

static int co_level = 8;
// Periodic timer to check the state of the MQTT client
#define STATE_MACHINE_PERIODIC     (CLOCK_SECOND >> 1)
static struct etimer periodic_timer;
static int period = 0;

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*
 * The main MQTT buffers.
 * We will need to increase if we start publishing more data.
 */

#define APP_BUFFER_SIZE 512
static char app_buffer[APP_BUFFER_SIZE];
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

static struct mqtt_message *msg_ptr = 0;



static struct mqtt_connection conn;



mqtt_status_t status;

char broker_address[CONFIG_IP_ADDR_STR_LEN];



/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

PROCESS(mqtt_client_process, "MQTT Client");







/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

static void

pub_handler(const char *topic, uint16_t topic_len, const uint8_t *chunk,

            uint16_t chunk_len)

{

  printf("Pub Handler: topic='%s' (len=%u), chunk_len=%u\n", topic,

          topic_len, chunk_len);

  char expected_topic[20];

  sprintf(expected_topic, "client%d/consistency", node_id);

  if(strcmp((const char *)topic, expected_topic) == 0){

    printf("Received Actuator command\n");



    if (strcmp((const char *)chunk, "moderate")==0){

    co_level = co_level - random_rand()%(35-20+1); 

    }else if (strcmp((const char *)chunk, "high")==0){

    co_level = co_level - random_rand()%(95-55+1);

    }else{

        printf("No data.\n");

    }

    return;

  }

}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

static void

mqtt_event(struct mqtt_connection *m, mqtt_event_t event, void *data)

{

  switch(event) {

  case MQTT_EVENT_CONNECTED: {

    printf("Application has a MQTT connection\n");



    state = STATE_CONNECTED;

    break;

  }

  case MQTT_EVENT_DISCONNECTED: {

    printf("MQTT Disconnect. Reason %u\n", *((mqtt_event_t *)data)); 



    state = STATE_DISCONNECTED;

    process_poll(&mqtt_client_process);

    break;

  }

  case MQTT_EVENT_PUBLISH: {

    msg_ptr = data;



    pub_handler(msg_ptr->topic, strlen(msg_ptr->topic),

                msg_ptr->payload_chunk, msg_ptr->payload_length);

    break;

  }

  case MQTT_EVENT_SUBACK: {

#if MQTT_311

    mqtt_suback_event_t *suback_event = (mqtt_suback_event_t *)data;



    if(suback_event->success) {

      printf("Application is subscribed to topic successfully\n");

    } else {

      printf("Application failed to subscribe to topic (ret code %x)\n", suback_event->return_code);

    }

#else

    printf("Application is subscribed to topic successfully\n");

#endif

    break;

  }

  case MQTT_EVENT_UNSUBACK: {

    printf("Application is unsubscribed to topic successfully\n");

    break;

  }

  case MQTT_EVENT_PUBACK: {

    printf("Publishing complete.\n");

    break;

  }

  default:

    printf("Application got a unhandled MQTT event: %i\n", event);

    break;

  }

}



static bool

have_connectivity(void)

{

  if(uip_ds6_get_global(ADDR_PREFERRED) == NULL ||

     uip_ds6_defrt_choose() == NULL) {

    return false;

  }

  return true;

}



/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

PROCESS_THREAD(mqtt_client_process, ev, data)

{



  PROCESS_BEGIN();



  printf("MQTT Client Process\n");



  // Initialize the ClientID as MAC address

  snprintf(client_id, BUFFER_SIZE, "%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x",

                     linkaddr_node_addr.u8[0], linkaddr_node_addr.u8[1],

                     linkaddr_node_addr.u8[2], linkaddr_node_addr.u8[5],

                     linkaddr_node_addr.u8[6], linkaddr_node_addr.u8[7]);



  // Broker registration                     

  mqtt_register(&conn, &mqtt_client_process, client_id, mqtt_event,

                  MAX_TCP_SEGMENT_SIZE);

                  

  state=STATE_INIT;

                    

  // Initialize periodic timer to check the status 

  etimer_set(&periodic_timer, STATE_MACHINE_PERIODIC);



  

  /* Main loop */

  

  while(1) {



    PROCESS_YIELD();



    if(ev== button_hal_press_event){

            co_level = co_level - 250;

            printf("/!\\ Emergency button pressed /!\\ \n CO level has fallen back to %d ppm.\n", co_level);

            sprintf(app_buffer, "{\"sensor\": %d, \"CO level\": %d}", node_id, co_level);

            mqtt_publish(&conn, NULL, pub_topic, (uint8_t *)app_buffer, strlen(app_buffer), MQTT_QOS_LEVEL_0, MQTT_RETAIN_OFF);

        }



    if((ev == PROCESS_EVENT_TIMER && data == &periodic_timer) || 

          ev == PROCESS_EVENT_POLL){

                          

          if(state==STATE_INIT){

             if(have_connectivity()==true)  

                 state = STATE_NET_OK;

          } 

          

          if(state == STATE_NET_OK){

              // Connect to MQTT server

              printf("Connecting!\n");

              

              memcpy(broker_address, broker_ip, strlen(broker_ip));

              

              mqtt_connect(&conn, broker_address, DEFAULT_BROKER_PORT,

                           (DEFAULT_PUBLISH_INTERVAL * 3) / CLOCK_SECOND,

                           MQTT_CLEAN_SESSION_ON);

              state = STATE_CONNECTING;

          }

          

          if(state==STATE_CONNECTED){

          

              // Subscribe to a topic

              char topic[20];

              sprintf(topic, "client%d/consistency", node_id);

              strcpy(sub_topic, topic);



              status = mqtt_subscribe(&conn, NULL, sub_topic, MQTT_QOS_LEVEL_0);



              printf("Subscribing!\n");

              if(status == MQTT_STATUS_OUT_QUEUE_FULL) {

                LOG_ERR("Tried to subscribe but command queue was full!\n");

                PROCESS_EXIT();

              }

              

              state = STATE_SUBSCRIBED;

          }

        



        if(state == STATE_SUBSCRIBED && (period%60==0)){

            // Publish something

                sprintf(pub_topic, "%s", "CO_LVL");

            co_level =  co_level + random_rand()%(35-1+1);

            printf("CO level is: %d ppm\n", co_level);

            sprintf(app_buffer, "{\"sensor\": %d, \"CO level\": %d}", node_id, co_level);

                            

            mqtt_publish(&conn, NULL, pub_topic, (uint8_t *)app_buffer, strlen(app_buffer), MQTT_QOS_LEVEL_0, MQTT_RETAIN_OFF);

        

        } else if ( state == STATE_DISCONNECTED ){

           LOG_ERR("Disconnected from MQTT broker\n");  

           // Recover from error

        }

        

        etimer_set(&periodic_timer, STATE_MACHINE_PERIODIC);

            period++;

      

    }



  }



  PROCESS_END();

}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

i am currently working on a project in contiki cooja and from long stuck on this problem: despite running properly i am not receiving the data in mysql database, after little debugging i found the on_connect callback is not being called....i don't know the reason...please help me

Comment: `loop_forever` does what it says; loops forever (well, until `disconnect()` is called). This means the `client3.loop_forever()` and `client4.loop_forever()` lines are never reached (so those clients will not work). If you want multiple loops running concurrently then use `loop_start()` (or an alternative). I'm guessing this is your issue (you don't confirm if they do, in fact connect, and I'm not sure why the C code is relevant? - please provide more info). I would add that its not really clear why you need multiple connections?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). e.g. remove the database stuff and start with one connection.

Comment: minimal one works fine, i am receiving the pub msg from the broker..but there's some issue with this code which I want to figure out

The c code is the configuration code file for the mote in the contiki cooja, I am using paho-mqqt along with the cooja and the c file publishes and subscribes to the topics

Comment: Please edit all the empty lines out of the code, and remove any code not directly related to the problem. As @Brits mentioned on 1 of the many clients in the python code is actually running due to you only starting one event loop.

Comment: "minimal one works fine", then its not a minimal, **reproducible**, example. Add more code bit by bit until it fails and you will find the issue (possibly with an obvious fix, or feel free to add details here). Currently your code has a number of issues making it difficult to help (so I'm voting to close the question). The `C` code is irrelevant (if the messages are reaching the broker then it's job is done).